# Sudoers: alias already defined "<garbage>"

Tags: linux, sudo, sudoers

I defined the following file in `/etc/sudoers.d/50-apps`

```
Cmnd_Alias APPS=/usr/bin/systemctl start app-*, /usr/bin/systemctl stop app-*,\
                /etc/init.d/app1, /etc/init.d/app2

Cmnd_Alias LOGS=/usr/bin/less /var/log/*, /bin/tail -f /var/log/*, /bin/tail /var/log/*,\
                /bin/ls /var/log/*

%developers ALL= NOPASSWD: SETENV: APPS, LOGS
%testers ALL= NOPASSWD: SETENV: LOGS
```

The file works as expected, validated by `visudo` and blocks unwanted commands. But every time I execute a command with sudo I am greeted by this message before the actual output of the command:

```
john@appserver1:~$ sudo ls /var/log/mysql
/etc/sudoers.d/50-apps:2:51: Alias "" already defined
                     /etc/init.d/app1, /etc/init.d/app2
                                                       ^
/etc/sudoers.d/50-apps:5:40: Alias "�h6�U" already defined
                     /bin/ls /var/log/*
```

The garbage in the second line changes every run. What might be the problem?

*P.S. I know about path traversals and added fixes to it but let's keep this example simple.*

Comment: Similar thing, everything works, but for every alias it complains: `Alias "en_US.UTF-8" already defined` each time I run sudo. The system is Debian 11 (testing)

Answer (score 3):

This can happen if sudoers files are included twice, which can happen if
/etc/sudoers contains two lines with same meaning, such as:

```
    @includedir /etc/sudoers.d
    #includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

Now, all files in /etc/sudoers.d/ will be read twice and will cause warning above.